# UIControl - addTarget: action: forControlEvents doesn't call the method inside selector

Tags: iphone, uicontrol, target-action

I have problem with adding target/action method to my app. Here's my code:

```
-(void)printInConsole
{
  NSLog(@"2");
}

-(void)createGCButton
{
  UIButton * LButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  LButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 90, 100, 50);
  [LButton setTitle:@"L" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.view addSubview:LButton];
  [LButton addTarget:self action:@selector(printInConsole)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

So first I tried one game center method and I didn't work. And now I add this simple NSLog method and it's also not working. The console don't write down nothing. So where's the problem. If you need more details about my code just say it and I will post it. God bless the one who solves this problem.

Regards, Klemen

Comment: When you press the button, does it look like it's being pressed (ie. does it change colors)?

Comment: Pasting this code into a clean project works, so the problem is not in the code you have posted. Are you by chance using UITapRecognizers on your view? Are you using ARC?

Comment: @Joel the button change the color

Comment: @PaulHunter I'm using both UITapRecognizers and ARC

Comment: This code is working good. clean your project & try again. Which xcode are you use?

Comment: @Jasmit I cleaned the project but the problem doesn't dissapear. I show the code to one developer and we come to conclusion that if I change control event to UIControlEventTouchDown, it works. Probably there is some view beside the button and it confuses everything. Im just the beginner in programming so it's hard for me to find errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very likely with the `UITapGestureRecognizer`. You can see this [blog post](http://www.sore.nu/blog/2012/apr/16/uitapgesturerecognizer-and-uibutton/) I made about the problem.

Basically you need to implement a `UITapGestureRecognizer` delegate method and tell it to not mess with buttons.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return ![touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];
}
```